# Connect PhoneGap App to MongoDB database

Tags: mongodb, cordova, database-connection, phonegap-plugins

I have created a website using an EC2 server and a MongoDB database. I am now trying to create an app for it, and cannot figure out the most basic way to connect to the database in phonegap and retrieve info. I was thinking of using the MongoDB driver for PHP, but I don't think that's possible for PhoneGap.

Any information would be appreciated. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Some options for you:

- Create your own backend web service which your app will talk to. Your backend talks to Mongo.
- Run an existing rest/http interface on top of your mongo instance. See https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/
- Use a hosted provider such as mlab.com who provide a rest API. See http://docs.mlab.com/data-api/